# How can I use VFS transport in WSO CEP 3.0?

Tags: file, wso2, complex-event-processing, vfs

I need write enents information into file. Can anybody show me example of output adapter for WSO2CEP 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is available from CEP 3.1.0 [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/mohan/CEP_3.1.0_Alpha/wso2cep-3.1.0.zip)

You can also follow the [CEP 3.0.0 doc](https://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP310/Writing+Custom+Event+Adaptors) and create your own adaptor